# Spring boot 404 not found Error message": "No message available

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, component-scan

Hello I'm working with a Spring boot App connecting to a mongo db, my problem is that my endpoint are not working it seems that they are not found by Component scan. I'm have been crazy because I'm blocked to continue developing and I'm not able to identify the issue. All seems to be ok. I suppose that maybe is something related with the versions, but not pretty sure.

This is my controller:

```
package com.mercadolibre.mutants.controllers;

import com.mercadolibre.mutants.entities.Product;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);
  public static final String SHORTEN_URL_PATH = "/shorten";
  public static final String URL_PATH = "/{id}";

  
  @RequestMapping(value = SHORTEN_URL_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public CompletableFuture<String> shortenUrl(@RequestBody @Valid final Product shortenUrlDto, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Url to shorten: " );
    CompletableFuture<String> shortenedUrl = null;
    String localURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    //shortenedUrl = shortUrlService.shortenURL(localURL, shortenUrlDto.getUrl());
    LOGGER.info("Shortened url to: " + shortenedUrl);
    return shortenedUrl;
  }

  @GetMapping(URL_PATH)
  public CompletableFuture<String> retrieveOriginalUrl(@PathVariable String id) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("short url to redirect: " + id);
    //CompletableFuture<String> redirectUrlString = shortUrlService.getLongURLFromID(id);
    //  LOGGER.info("Original URL: " + redirectUrlString);
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is my Application class:

```
package com.mercadolibre.mutants;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication()
public class MutantsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MutantsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.16.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mercadolibre</groupId>
    <artifactId>mutants</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mutants</name>
    <description>Project for Java Challengue</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Lovelace-SR9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Hello, I just try your code an it works, I could make the request to the endpoints you have. Could you give me a hint about how are you making the request?

Comment: just like that:  localhost:8080/shorten in a post in postman

Comment: Same here, I'm making a POST to http://localhost:8080/shorten from Postman and it works. Are you getting some error in the log? Could you share the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm using docker compose, maybe it could be related?

Comment: Could be, so you are deploying your api inside a docker image? Could you give a detailed explanation of how are you deploying and testing?

Comment: Yes, but I've done others similar and it worked without problems so I think it is not related. But not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I would say you have a problem with the docker configuration where you are deploying your api, I would do the next validations:

1. Check your api is being served in the 8080 inside your docker container.
2. Check if you have correctly configured your docker container so the 8080 port (or the one used by your api) is open.
3. Check if (for some strange reason) you don't have another api running in 8080 in the docker container.

Finally, get into the SSH of your container and then (if you are running some UNIX SO) make a CURL request to the url and check the answer.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: But the application responds, it means that it is served in the port 8080, the problem is that is responds with a 404 not found.

Comment: Could you share the .properties file please?

Comment: My .properties is empty

Comment: All your .properties? What about the bootstrap.properties? Check if your api is not running with a root context. Did you tried to make the CURL inside the docker container?